# How to get the date values from database inside foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

It's already working but the holidays only.I already connected the database inside foreach loop and minus the holiday in fines  [the table in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upt5M.png) and table in my website already count it as holiday [table in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1RqO.png) but after I add another holiday in database like September 6 and the result is like this "imgur.com/a/l8Deq" not counted as holiday and don't know why my fines and days are increasing. What should I do? Thank you for helping me

```
$borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_return'],new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));
$returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date'],new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila')); 
$currentdate = new Datetime('Asia/Manila');

$returndate->setTime(0,0);
$currentdate->setTime(0,0);
$borrowdate->setTime(0,0);

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($returndate, $interval, $borrowdate);

$borrowdate->format("D");
$weekendDays = 0;
$totalDays = 0;
$holiDays = 0;


$query_holiday =mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM holiday_tbl"); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_holiday)){                   
$holi = $row ['holiday'];                                          

foreach ($period as $p ) 
{
   $totalDays++;
   if($p->format( "w" )== 0 or $p->format( "w" )==6 ) $weekendDays++;
   if($p->format('Y-m-d') == $holi) $holiDays++;

 }
 }
echo "<p>Total  days: $totalDays</p><p>Weekend days: $weekendDays </p> <p>                 Holidays: $holiDays </p>";
$fines = ($totalDays - $weekendDays - $holiDays) * 5;
echo "₱ ". $fines;
$fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
```

Comment: You have a foreach loop inside a while loop. $totalDays will be incremented for number of days per period times number of holidays. If you only want the count of days per period, you don't want to count them again each time you have a holiday.

Comment: @TimMorton sorry I don't know what to do so I did that code eventually I thought it's ok but when  I add another date in holidays from database then the problem comes up